# How to compare audio in android?

Tags: android, audio

I'm making an application in which I record a direct audio from the microphone of the cell phone, I save that recording and I need to compare it with some audio already stored in the device
The audios are of "noise" of motors, the idea is that from the recorded recording it indicates us to which case of the saved ones it seems
that is, I have two cases, a good engine and a damaged engine, when I finish recording it must say "this audio belongs to a damaged engine"

Reading I find that it has to be done through artificial intelligence, which is really complex, I have read that you can "decompose" the audio into a vector of numbers or make comparisons by FFT, however I do not find much information about it, really I'd appreciate your help.

the file type saved is .wav

Answer (score 0):

It's nontrivial task to compare audio signals.

The audio is just a sequence of values (numbers) where index is just a "time" and value is a loudness of sound (amplitude).

If you compare audio data like two arrays (sequences) element by element, iterating through the index - it will be luck to get something reasonable. Though you need some transformation of this array to get aggregated info about this sequence of numbers as a whole (for example - spectre of signal).

There are some mathematical tools for this task, for example, mentioned by you well-known [Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) and statistical tool [Autocorrelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) (it finds "kindness" of sequence of numbers).

The **autocorrelation** method can be relatively simple - you just iterate comparing arrays of data and calculate the autocorrelation. But you will pay for simplicity in case of initial quality (or preparation/normalization) of signals - they should have similar duration. The value of resulted correlation function will show how differ two sequences, i.e. `0` - is absolutely different and `1` - is almost the same.

To implement **Fourier Transform** (FFT) is not a problem too, you could take well described algo and implement it itself on any language without using third party libs. It does the job very well.

FT will help you get a spectrum of the signal i.e. another set of values: set of  amplitudes per frequency (roughly, frequency as array index instead of time in case of input raw signal) and now you can compare this given spectrums almost like two arrays iterating through an index (frequency) and then decide on their similarity - calculate deltas and see whether it hit into some acceptance interval (or you can use more correct statistical methods e.g. *correlation function*).

As for **noised signal**, the noise is usually subtracted from the given data set (but here you should know the sort of noise type).

It is all related to signal processing area and if you're working on such project you need to learn more about this.

Bonus: [a book for example](http://www.dspguide.com/)